# PHP:mySQL: Not able to update all the rows in the data base. Table is getting partially updated

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm experiencing a strange behavior, where I'm not able to update all the rows successfully in the database.

I have a PHP web page that displays some data after fetching it from MYSQL. The webpage also gives flexibility to the user to make any edits, and after making changes and clicking Update button, the values in the text boxes gets updated in the database.
The problem that I'm getting is that only first 60 rows are being updated instead of all 177.

This is a small web page having the values after user made the updates. Lets say, user updated Rihaana to Eminem.

```
ID      FieldText
01      Slim Shady
02      Dr. Dre
05      Rihaana -->> 'Eminem'
```

Using AJAX, I have sent the json file to the php file, where I'm extracting the values and updating it in the database.
My JSON looks like:

```
array(2) {
["fieldText"]=>
array(177) {
[0]=>
string(55) "Slim Shady"
[1]=>
string(24) "Dr Dre"
[2]=>
string(27) "Eminem"
}
["ID"]=>
array(177) {
[0]=>
string(1) "1"
[1]=>
string(1) "2"
[2]=>
string(1) "5"
}}
```

JSON generated is valid one. 
The actual length of JSON is **177**

Once the json is being sent to php file, I'm splitting the json code into 2 arrays and length of both the arrays is 177.

Now what I'm doing next is for every ID, I'm fetching field Text and would like to update it in the database.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($_POST['postData'],true);
$length = count($jsonData['ID']); ## The length is 177 in my json
$ID = $jsonData['ID']; ## The length is 177 in my json
$fieldText = $jsonData['fieldText']; ## The length is 177 in my json
```

Now, with below code, I'm updating all the values in the row using for loop, but this loop is running for 60 iterations only not 177(as expected):

```
for($j=0; $j< count($jsonData['ID']); $j++) {

$langText = $fieldText[$j];
$id = (int) $ID[$j];

$update = "UPDATE languageUpdate  SET fieldText = '$langText'
                WHERE ID = $id";
                //echo "$update";
$mysqli->query($update) or die(mysql_error());}}
```

I tried doing debugging, but not able to do so. Can someone please help out.

Comment: Try to replace "count($jsonData['ID'])" with "$length" in your for loop

Comment: I did that as well, but not working

Comment: Can you explain how you know there are only 60 iterations ?

Comment: ok provide your full json array, so i can read that and find solution

Comment: I echoed $id in the for loop. Shows me 1234..60. Also, If i update initial few rows it gets updated successfully, however the later rows doesn't.

Comment: $id shown 1234...60 ? Seems strange to me since first ids seem to be 1/2/5. Did you echo $j maybe ?

Comment: @LaljiNakum I've posted the sample json above. its more or less same, but with confidential data. Basically, I need a loop that can extract values from json like this {1 , Slim Shady}, {2, Dr Dre}, {5. Eminem} and then update the database.

Comment: @MateoBarahona: this is sample data that I created.. but I have a continuous array of length 177. I echoed $id

Comment: Did you check you're not going to the "die" ? It would happen if you a simple quote if $langText, for example.

Comment: @MateoBarahona: I commented the sql update code and found that $j is working fine and is showing 176, as expected. But what could be the root cause of Die.. any idea..?

Comment: @user4943236 : Check my answer, I think that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 177 items, the problem lies with the query, not the loop. It probably fails and then go to the **die** statement.

Display `$update` and check the last one before it fails (but you should be able to find the error by looking at mysql_error()).
My guess is you have a simple quote in `$langText` or any other bad character.
Escape your variable, it's a good practice :

```
$update = "UPDATE languageUpdate
SET fieldText = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($langText)."'
WHERE ID = $id";
```

Comment: Let me check and get back to you

Comment: i noticed if I run the query by using insert into statement; all the rows gets updated successfully. But if I run it using php, why it is dying? Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: Did you display the last query called before it fails ? Can you give me the $langText used at that point ?

Comment: Sure. I'm travelling at this moment.. Will send you the text in half an hour. Hope you would be able to help then.. Sorry.: or possible to come to chat ??

Comment: Yep sure, we can chat

Comment: Mateo, how do I come to chat? can you forward the link please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94098/discussion-between-user4943236-and-mateo-barahona).